# Blank input from Overleaf standalone

Tags: pstricks, standalone, overleaf

The following MWE gives me three pages of output in [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/nzswmqhqfmxh).

Project `semilog6655`:

```
\documentclass[multi=false,pstricks=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\include{TECcolors}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5.4,-5)(5.4,5.4)
  \psgrid[
           gridcolor=TECaubergine,
           subgridcolor=TECaubergine,
           gridlabels=0
         ](-5,-5)(5,5)
  \psaxes[
          linecolor=TECsennepsgul,
          linewidth=2pt,
          Dy=1,
          ylogBase=10,
          Oy=0
         ]
    {->}(0,0)(-5.4,-5)(5.4,5.4)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The two first pages are unintentionally blank 
while the third page shows the desired graphics.

Correspondingly, I get a blank box (or am I expressing , when I import the file
into some other project:

```
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{semilog6655.pdf}
```

The same output, I get from the following command:

```
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{semilog6655}
```

Comment: Unnecessary `%` is distracting.

Comment: I use `%` sign routinely to signal extension of a command across lines. Would that be considered bad style?

Comment: You can separate key-value pairs across lines without `%`. Using many unnecessary `%` is not a good style.

Comment: Point taken, edited

Comment: @Engelsmann: it is _not_ a _bad_ style using the `%`. They are superflous in _this_ case, but not in other cases!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
\input{TECcolors}
```

and not

```
\include{TECcolors}
```

See [When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include) for the differences.

Using `\include` there actually gives an error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\set@color ->\special {color push \current@color 
                                                 }\aftergroup \reset@color 
l.8 \include{TECcolors}

?
```

which Overleaf for some reason doesn't report.

---

Regarding the last part, if you include a multi-page PDF with `\includegraphics`, you get the first page by default I think. You can change which page to include, e.g.

```
\includegraphics[width=5cm,page=3]{semilog6655}
```

to get the third page. (If you don't specify the extension, LaTeX has a list of extensions it tries, I don't know the order, but PDF is certainly among them.)